# Converting a Portable Class Library Project .csproj file from Version 2 (Beta) back to Version 1

Tags: monodevelop, visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library

I'm trying to move a lot of code backwards and forwards between the VS10, VS11 and MonoDevelop3 a lot at present.

It seems that MonoDevelop3 has some initial support for PCL1, but VS10 and VS11 are now both using PCL2(Beta) - because I installed VS11 on the same PC as VS10.

In order to allow MonoDevelop3 to load these PCL2(Beta) projects, I'm trying to manipulate the PCL projects by hand.

It seems like this is not just as simple as changing the TargetProfile in the .csproj XML file - it seems like more is needed... but I can't work out what.

Does anyone know what the exact differences are between PCL2 and PCL1? Or how I might manually convert PCL2 project files so that they can be loaded into MonoDevelop?

Thanks

Stuart

An example PLP2 project file looks a bit like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{B6E27475-E7D0-448C-A5CC-5097DCA1E2DD}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Cirrious.MvvmCross</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Cirrious.MvvmCross</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile104</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Application\MvxApplication.cs" />
    etc
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this question now.

After looking into this at great length... it seems there aren't any significant differences between the project files.

Instead, it seems that the monoDevelop support for these files is still in its youth and **you must use Profile1** if you want these files to open in MonoDevelop (3.0.2)

So use:

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile1</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

Not

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile2</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```